# How to use Windows Authentication in a HTTP/2 web app (on IIS)

Tags: iis, windows-authentication, http2

IIS 10 supports HTTP/2 but it downgrades to HTTP/1.1 if the web site is configured to use Windows Authentication.

I would like to create a web application that doesn't require domain users to log in (Windows Auth is perfect for that) but still being able to use HTTP/2.
Do you have ideas about how to design that?

My own thoughts so far:
Maybe I could take the Windows Auth outside the app into a different service that creates a JWT and then use that JWT to authenticate on the main app.

That adds a lot of complexity, though:

- Chrome currently doesn't mix HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1 in the same domain (FF does), so that service has to be on a different domain, implying an additional SSL certificate + DNS config, etc.
- I would need to handle JWT expiration during any call to the server.

So that might be too much effort for what it's worth.

Can you think of a better idea?

Comment: In a few cases, HTTP/2 can't be used in combination with other features. Windows authentication is not supported with HTTP/2. In this case IIS will fall back to HTTP/1.1.

Comment: I know, that's the 1st sentence in my question. I'm interested in a "workaround" design where you could still authenticate users automatically _and_ use HTTP/2 for the main web app. Ideally without adding too much complexity.

Comment: The JWT auth proxy would make a great sample!  Considering using https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy if you know C#.

Answer (score 3):

> IIS 10 supports HTTP/2 but it downgrades to HTTP/1.1 if the web site is configured to use Windows Authentication.

Correct. [This is because Windows Authentication does not support HTTP/2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis).

> I would like to create a web application that doesn't require domain users to log in (Windows Auth is perfect for that) but still being able to use HTTP/2

There are no real advantages to running HTTP/2 in a LAN environment. HTTP/2 (and HTTP/3) are designed to keep user-perceivable latency down, which isn't a problem in LAN environments. HTTP/2 also requires TLS, which is not widely deployed in a LAN (as you can't use a public CA for non-public addresses, so you need to setup and maintain your own PKI, without that you can't use HTTP/2 anyway. Most small-businesses running their own Active Directory domain won't be running their own PKI and they won't be able to use HTTP/2 *at all* for internal applications - unless you *really* want to instruct your users to force-trust a self-signed certificate).

> My own thoughts so far: Maybe I could take the Windows Auth outside the app into a different service that creates a JWT and then use that JWT to authenticate on the main app.

Actually, **this is a perfectly fine option!**. <sub>(I didn't even think of this approach before I started writing my response.)</sub> You can implement this with a simple `http://localhost:12345` listener that your application's logon page (at `http://lan-server:80/`) can interrogate using `fetch` in a client-script or an `<iframe>` and use that to auto-sign-in. Another alternative is to set-up a Chrome extension (which are largely compatible with MS Edge, Firefox and Safari now too) to make the requests to the localhost listener and update the user's `http://lan-server` cookies. You're lucky that a huge advantage of working in a LAN environment is that you don't have to worry about client-side software deployment because you (or your IT dept) can ensure that it's all set-up already.

> Chrome currently doesn't mix HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1 in the same domain (FF does), so that service has to be on a different domain, implying an additional SSL certificate + DNS config, etc.

Correct.

The infrastructure and configuration issues you're experiencing are a significant reason why internal and "enterprise-y" web-applications are disappearing: software-vendors don't want to have to maintain tech-support for on-prem installations, and the companies that use them don't want to have to maintain an on-prem system. Previously companies had *massive* trust issues (as in *human trust*, not PKI trust) in allowing another company to host their own corporate data, emails, documents and the like - in addition to the lack of availability of 100mbps+ low-latency internet connections which made many kinds of applications simply impossible - but that's been a reality for most of the past decade now and hence why there's probably now an order-of-magnitude more companies using Office 365 E-mail users than those on-prem Exchange Server today. It wouldn't surprise me if Microsoft themselves *kill-off* Windows Server and traditional Active Directory make it all one massive Azure/Office 365/Internet-managed mega-MDM system - at least that way you could join an AD domain (or whatever they call it at that point) without needing to be physically connected to your on-prem LAN or having to VPN-in.

> I would need to handle JWT expiration during any call to the server.

This isn't a problem for two reasons:

1. While it's true that a JWT has a defined expiration date+time, client software will renews any JWTs long before it's due to expire. Applications *don't* wait to refresh an `access_token` until after it's already expired: they do it *before* it expires.

   <sub>For example: in OAuth2/OIDC the `refresh_token` is not a JWT, but is a short string (which generally *doesn't* expire), and the client software uses the `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token` (which *is* a JWT) without risking that the `access_token` expires. Microsoft's own OIDC client in ASP.NET will renew an `access_token` about half-way past the `access_token`'s stated maximum-age - so if at-time-of-issue, a JWT `access_token`'s expiry is 24 hours away, the client will renew the `access_token` after 12 hours. Thus eliminating the risk of the client using an expired JWT.</sub>
2. A JWT's expiration is generally-speaking only checked once: when the request hits the server - requests are handled instantly (HTTP is stateless, remember?) so it *doesn't matter* if a JWT expires 3 seconds after it starts making a request for an operation that takes 10 seconds to process. <sub>(well, unless the `access_token` is being forwarded to *another* resource-server, in which case that's a crappy application design)</sub>.

> So that might be too much effort for what it's worth.

I argue *what it's worth* depends on your application. It sounds to me like you want to be able to say that your application supports HTTP/2 for some advertising bullet-point or competitive product comparison page - in which case that's a bad reason for wanting to *do anything*. But as far as **on-prem** LAN applications are concerned "HTTP/2 support" means *so little* that even you mentioning it is implicitly making an dishonest comparison that appeals only to people who should not be making software procurement decisions - and the people that do know it means bollocks will consequently take a dim view of your product.

---

As an advice for you as a developer or solution provider: don't look at where the ball is; look at where the ball is heading: and it's heading further into *the cloud*. Look around and see that on-prem business software and web-applications now offer little advantages over globally-accessible Internet SaaS application hosting. By compromising your product to support a declining environment you'll lose your ability to compete with those thinking ahead of you. Now - I assume you're in this for profit... and if you are then *I hope* that you are choosing your target-markets correctly because on-prem is only going to dwindle-down from here.

Comment: So I suppose the answer to the question "can you think of a better idea?" is "no".
Thanks for taking the time to write these comments about http/2; you make lots of invalid assumptions regarding my project.
This isn't a low-latency LAN, I literally have users at the antipode. TLS isn't a problem, it's a requirement for every deployment (large enterprise here). We do web because of the ease of access, if I deploy something on the client computer (a plugin), I'd rather not make a web app. No way this is headed to the cloud.

Comment: "There are no real advantages to running HTTP/2 in a LAN environment" so microsoft does not believe in any company possibly growing to a multinational size?

Comment: HTTP/2 can have a significant advantage, even in a LAN environment, if you have multiple requests in parallel and some potentially take a long time. It solves the [head of line blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45583977/909237).

Comment: I write small web apps for equities traders (Wall St.), and our traders work on VPN sometimes (bad weather, sometimes they can't come into the office and have to do their work from home, think COVID but just for 1-3 days).  I'm interested in web app Windows Auth + HTTP3, which I think is getting a big perf boost in .NET 7 (is out, but I'm not using it yet) and .NET 8 (if you need to wait until LTS is available).

Comment: @yzorg I haven't looked at http/3 support yet. Does IIS support WinAuth with http/3? That would be nice :)

Comment: IIS supports HTTP/3 under a flag in 2022.  But yes, I assume all widely used features would be supported under a new protocol, including WinAuth, especially since Chrome and Edge have supported HTTP/3 for years now (as QUIC has evolved into HTTP/3).